# Angular's AuthGuard allways return false on page refresh, but I am authenticated

Tags: angular, auth-guard

I am creating login system in my Angular application. Everything works fine, I have just one problem with my AuthGuard. When I refresh the page in which implement 'canActivate: [AuthGuard]' it redirects me to login and i get isAuth = false. But from there I can go back to my guarded page without login.

AuthGuard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private userAuthService: UserAuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | boolean
    | UrlTree
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    const isAuth = this.userAuthService.getIsAuth();
    console.log(isAuth + ' at auth.guard.ts');

    if (!isAuth) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    return isAuth;
  }
}
```

And my UserAuthService file:

```
  private authStatusListener = new Subject<boolean>();
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
  private token: string | null = '';

 getIsAuth() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }

  getAuthStatusListener() {
    return this.authStatusListener.asObservable();
  }

  login(user: UserLogin) {
    const url = environment.apiUrl + '/auth/login/';

    this.http.post<{ token: string }>(url, user).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        const token = res.token;
        this.token = token;
        if (this.token) {
          this.isAuthenticated = true;
          this.authStatusListener.next(true);
          this.storeJwtToken(this.token);
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        } else {
          this.isAuthenticated = false;
          this.authStatusListener.next(false);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        this.authStatusListener.next(false);
      }
    );
  }

  autoAuthUser() {
    const token = this.getJwtToken();
    if (token) {
      this.token = token;
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.authStatusListener.next(true);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  storeJwtToken(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

  getJwtToken(): any {
    const token: any = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return token;
  }
```

And in my app.component.ts file I am just doing this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userAuthService.autoAuthUser();
  }
```

Comment: It's because you're employing a bad practice. If you're waiting for an async operation, you should return the operation itself (as observable or promise), in this case, auth guard doesn't wait for your async operation just returns false. Then post request comes and sets isAuthenticated to true but since guard has already returned false (before the server response), it does not change the behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it is allways returning false on refresh.. Do you have any suggestion how can I change logic in my AuthGuard file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a promise (async) function in your UserAuthService and provide that function in app.module.ts as dependency. So, it will wait until resolves the promise of your async function before starting the app. With this you will be already logged in when your app starts or refresh.
UserAuthService:

```js
  async init(): Promise<any>{
    this.autoAuthUser();
  }
```

app.module.ts:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    UserAuthService,
    {
      //With this your app will wait to resolve the promise of init() of your UserAuthService.
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
      useFactory: (service: UserAuthService) => function() { return service.init();},
      deps: [UserAuthService],
      multi: true
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Another way**

You can simply redirect from your autoAuthUser() function.

AuthGuard:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private userAuthService: UserAuthService,
    private router: Router,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ){
    const isAuth = this.userAuthService.getIsAuth();
    console.log(isAuth + ' at auth.guard.ts');
    if (!isAuth) {
      //Here you pass queryParams with last url from state.url.
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    }
    return isAuth;
  }
}
```

UserAuthService :

```js
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router){}

autoAuthUser() {
    const token = this.getJwtToken();
    if (token) {
      this.token = token;
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.authStatusListener.next(true);
      // Here you redirect to the last URL or '/'.
      this.router.navigateByUrl(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/');
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It redirects me to the right url, but this still is not the most optimal solution. I still get isAuth = false in my console.log from auth.guard.ts file

Comment: You can try to call autoAuthUser() from constructor of your UserAuthService. 
And remove it from ngOnInit of app.component.ts

Comment: I managed it to work. I provided async f iunction in my service and provided it in app.module.ts as dependancy and it works now. Thanks

Comment: Nice, happy to hear. And sorry for not responding you other day, I had been busy at work.

Comment: Thank you and no problem. If you think my question could help some people, feel free to give it a vote :)

Answer (score 1):

You can return an `Observable` in `canActivate` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate))

You can just use the `getAuthStatusListener` in the guard instead of that boolean.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private userAuthService: UserAuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | boolean
    | UrlTree
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {

    return this.userAuthService.getAuthStatusListener().pipe(
      take(1),
      map(isAuthenticated => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }

        return isAuthenticated;
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Also, in your service, you need to emit false on the else of `autoAuthUser`

```js
autoAuthUser() {
  const token = this.getJwtToken();
    
  this.token = token;
  this.isAuthenticated = !!token;
  this.authStatusListener.next(!!token);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't allow me to visit guarded route.  I also don't get any error in my console, and in map function I console.log(isAuthenticated) and it doesn't even come here to execute this line of code

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz example with minimal reproduction? It seems weird for it not to trigger. Does the `authStatusListener` emit in your case?

Comment: oh, it's because of the else in `autoAuthUser`. you need to emit `this.authStatusListener.next(false);` I updated the response as well

Comment: It sadly still doesn't trigger even with this change.

Comment: are you sure the method `autoAuthUser` is triggered? Can you `console.log` inside of it? If it doesn't go inside the `map` function it means that `next` is never triggered. In this case, maybe you need to combine calling the method on `APP_INITIALIZER` with this solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246332/discussion-between-devz-and-cristian-florin-calina).